# Compute this limit using the relation between Riemann and Lebesgue integral

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Can anyone help me compute the following limit?
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{ \int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{nx^{1/n}}{ne^x+\sin(nx)}\right)dx}$$

Using the relation between Riemann and Lebesgue integral and Lebesgue’s Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, we have $f_n(x) = { \sqrt[n]{x} \over e^x + x { \sin (nx) \over nx} } $, and since
$ |\operatorname{sinc} x|\le 1$, we have
$f_n(x) \le { \sqrt[n]{x} \over e^x - x }  \le { \max(1,x) \over 1+{1 \over 2!} x^2 +{1 \over 3!} x^3 }$, and since the latter is integrable, we can
use the dominated convergence theorem to
swap the integration and limit to get $\int f_n \to \int f$, where
$f(x) = e^{-x}$. The latter integral is straightforward to evaluate.

Comment: I understand the dominated convergence theorem there but how do you conclude that $f(x) = e^{-x}$?

Comment: For a fixed $x \neq 0$, $\sqrt[n]{x} \to 1$ and $\operatorname{sinc} (nx) \to 0$, we get $f_n(x) \to {1 \over e^x + 0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that  for $x>0$,
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{nx^{1/n}}{ne^x+\sin(nx)}=
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{x^{1/n}}{e^x+\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}=e^{-x}.$$
Moreover for $n\geq 2$,
$$0\leq\frac{nx^{1/n}}{ne^x+\sin(nx)}=\frac{x^{1/n}}{e^x+\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}\leq \frac{\max(1,x)}{e^x-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Comment: Because $x^{1/n}\to 1$ and $\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\to 0$ (bounded by infinitesimal)